# Use of fx:constant in attributes?

Tags: javafx-2, constants, fxml

I am wondering, is it somehow possible to use `<fx:constant>` in an attribute instead of a separate tag?

Currently this works for me:

```
<Label>
    <text>
        <MyController fx:constant="MY_CONSTANT_STRING" />
    </text>
</Label>
```

while I would prefer something like this:

```
<Label text="<MyController fx:constant="MY_CONSTANT_STRING" />" />
```

Is something like the later possible?

Thanks for any hint!